# Cloudinary get video duration with resources

Tags: node.js, cloudinary

How to get Cloudinary video duration along with the other properties using Node.js & cloudinary.v2.api.resources?

Haven't you read the other posts about the topic? Yes I have. They all say pass in `image_metadata: true`. Does not work.

I am searching like this:

```
cloudinary.api.resources(
  {
    ...
    image_metadata: true,
  },
  (err: any, result: any) => {
    console.log(err, result);
  }
);
```

Passing in image_metadata: true, does not return video duration. Well, it does not change anything to be fair, while I get everything else I want.

Am I missing an update on this? Been searching for it a while now but no result.
Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: that parameter was updated to `media_metadata`, can you try with `media_metadata: true`?

Comment: Hey @Tom. No luck. Updated the package as types still suggested `image_metadata` but even with the updated packages when i check out the types there is no `media_metadata`

Comment: Found this API reference table. The last row says `metadata` as a boolean. Unfortunately this does not seem to be working either. :/

https://cloudinary.com/documentation/admin_api#get_resources

Comment: yeah actually i don't think get_resources supports metadata param, only works when you use the get_resources_for_single_resource (https://cloudinary.com/documentation/admin_api#get_the_details_of_a_single_resource)

as a workaround you can use the Search API instead which allows you which metadata fields the response should include, see https://cloudinary.com/documentation/search_api (with_field parameter).

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
cloudinary.v2.api.resource(public_id, {
  resource_type: "video",
  media_metadata: true,
});
```

By default the cloudinary api pings its /image api. You have to declare video, and then request metadata to get the duration.